# Database query ignores the first row from the table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a problem with getting a result of the first row from the table. It just ignores it and results the second row instead.

The query needs to result the highest or equal value to **column_b** from the value given in **textBox1**.

i.e if I enter **12** into the **textBox1**, the result should be: **column_a = 1,5** | **column_b = 18,5**
But it ignores the first row and gives a result of **column_a = 2,5** | **column_b = 25**

**Example of the table being used:**

```
+----------+----------+
| column_a | column_b |
+----------+----------+
|   1,5    |   18,5   |
|   2,5    |    25    |
|    4     |    34    |
|    6     |    47    |
+----------+----------+
```

**The code:**

```cs
//Table used from database    
string tableused = "main_table";

//Connecting to Database
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=data\\db\\database.mdb");
connection.Open();

//Database Query    
OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand();
select.Connection = connection;
select.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 column_a,column_b FROM " + tableused + " WHERE column_b+0 >=" + textBox1.Text + "+0 ORDER BY column_b+0 ASC";

//Reading the query output   
OleDbDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
         label5.Text = (reader[0].ToString());
         label6.Text = (reader[1].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
```

Anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: What are the data types of column_a and column_b? Why are you using `+0`?

Comment: The data type for them is text. Without the `+0` I get an exception "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are using Text as data type for your numeric values.

What's happening now with your `+0` code is that you are querying values of `18.50`, `250` etc. And `250` is larger or equals your input `+0`, e.g. `120`. `18.50` is smaller, so it is not returned in the result set.

Microsoft Access does a lot of implicit conversion, yes, but you cannot trust it like you are doing.

If you want numeric values, use numeric data types.

Comment: if I make the data type Numeric value, it drops the commas. It just ignores the first row. All other rows work fine. I forgot to add that adding `+0` makes the values result in the right order. Not doing so will give result random rows

Comment: Yes all other rows work because all other rows don't have your comma. Use the `Double` data type, not `Integer` or `Long`. 

You're expecting the comma to be recognized as a decimal mark, but your implicit data type conversions thinks it is a 'thousands separator'.

Comment: Thank you it worked! I'm using Microsoft Access 2013, and I didn't realize that when you make the data type Numeric you also have to define what kind of numeric type it is.By default it's long integer. Setting the value to double made it to work!

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander points out, your `+"0"` whose purpose is to force a conversion is the problem.

It is a common error to store numbers and dates in a text field, just because you want them appear in a certain format. Always store the data in a format neutral format, i.e. numbers in a number field and dates in a date or date/time field.

Apply the desired format when displaying the field, i.e. when converting the value to a `string`.

If you are constructing a SQL command with string concatenations you have the problem that you have to convert value to a literal valid for the SQL dialect and database culture used. It is not easy to find the right date literal but also numbers are problematic because of different thousands and decimal separators used in different cultures. Therefore (and in order to fight [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) always use command parameters. This is not possible for the table name, but I assume that those are not entered by the user directly and that they are therefore safe (otherwise check if the table name is valid!).

```
double d;
if (Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out d)) {
    select.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 column_a, column_b FROM " + tableused + 
        " WHERE column_b >= @1 ORDER BY column_b ASC";
    select.AddWithValue("@1", d);
    ...
} else {
    // Number not valid
}
```